# auto increment row in xls and update it's values using python

Tags: python, excel, row, xls

Facing issue while automatically updating  an xls file ( Row and column) using python.

Example: ( This is for first and  second row, want to automatically increase the row values and correspondingly update it's values )

For first row

```
sheet1.write(0, 0, Number)
sheet1.write(0, 1, algo_type.tag)
sheet1.write(0, 2, ref_slope)
sheet1.write(0, 3, opt_slope)
sheet1.write(0, 4, angle)
```

For second row

```
sheet1.write(1, 0, Number)
sheet1.write(1, 1, algo_type.tag)
sheet1.write(1, 2, ref_slope)
sheet1.write(1, 3, opt_slope)
sheet1.write(1, 4, angle)
```

Please suggest how to takel this type of situations.

Thanks,
Niraj

Comment: use a variable for the row number.

Comment: Possibly you mean to auto-increment the `Number` field? Otherwise, as per others, use a variable in a for loop to update the row number.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `write` in a loop to increment the row number.

```
maxRows = 10   # or however many rows you want
for rowNumber in range(maxRows):
    sheet1.write(rowNumber, 0, Number)
    sheet1.write(rowNumber, 1, algo_type.tag)
    sheet1.write(rowNumber, 2, ref_slope)
    sheet1.write(rowNumber, 3, opt_slope)
    sheet1.write(rowNumber, 4, angle)
```

Comment: @ Mhawke : Here all the filed value(Number,algo_type.tag,ref_slope,opt_slope,angle) will be decided at run time. Actually my xls file will be                                                                  F No  Algo type    Ref_slope   Opt_slope  Angle  distance   Result 

1     Ransac     1.0     1.0     0.0     2.828      Fail
1     Ransac     1.0     1.0     0.0     2.828      Fail          Here values of all filed will be changing corresponding to it's row and column values, Size of row is not fixed.

Comment: Here is the code : It is updating the last value only, how can i get all the incremented row value in xls.                                         import xlwt

row_no=0
def xls_write(row_no):

 book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
 sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Result")
 frame_n = "Frame is "
 sheet1.write(row_no, 0,frame_n)
 
 book.save("D:/Desktop/Row_checking.xls")
 print "Current row_no is : " , row_no


xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)