# How to increment column in excel with python

Tags: python, excel

I have the below code where the columns need to increment and insert the correct texts.  I would like the column to increment but the sequence I tried did not work.

Working code:

```
worksheet1.write(10, 1, 'Test0')
worksheet1.write(10, 2, 'Test1')
worksheet1.write(10, 3, 'Test2')
worksheet1.write(10, 4, 'Test3')
worksheet1.write(10, 5, 'Test4')
```

Tried sequence did not work. Just ended up writing the last text "Test4".  Other text must have been overwritten.

Not Working Code:

```
m=0
worksheet1.write(10, m++1, 'Test0')
worksheet1.write(10, m++1, 'Test1')
worksheet1.write(10, m++1, 'Test2')
worksheet1.write(10, m++1, 'Test3')
worksheet1.write(10, m++1, 'Test4')
```

Comment: Try to make a loop to increment it. Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307265/12176979

Comment: Python does not have a "++" operator.  All 5 of those lines will be m+(+1), which is 1.  One tricky way is `import itertools` / `m = itertools.count(1)` / `worksheet1.write(10,m.next(), 'Test0')`.